# How Does PKaeding Do It?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

Ive come across this website, http://gmaps.kaeding.name/, which allows you to plot multiple locations on a static google map.

My question is how is this done..?  I'm not trying to copy what he's done, just understand as Im trying to achieve something similar.

In the blog it says "You enter as many addresses as you want, one per line. Then the script sends those strings through geocoder.us to get latitude and longitude"

Would this be a Visual Basic script...?  Or am I barking completely up the wrong tree...?

sorry to be so vague but not sure where to start

Comment: It could really be any language...Visual Basic, C#, Python, Perl.  It appears to be running on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

The form posts to cgi-bin/map.cgi on the server, so any attempt to work out the implementation would be pure guesswork. There are implementations of this functionality in pure client-side Javascript, if you care to Google them, such as this one:

http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/geocoding-uk-postcodes-with-google-map-api/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rely on geocoding per se, as the [Google Static Maps API](http://goo.gl/WXwq6) allows you to provide addresses for locations plotted on a static map as markers.

From the docs:

> Each marker descriptor must contain a set of one or more locations
>   defining where to place the marker on the map. These locations may be
>   either specified as latitude/longitude values or as addresses. These
>   locations are separated using the pipe character (|).

The Static Maps API includes features that allow you to overlay markers, lines, and polygons.  So to implement something similar, you'd simply collect the form field values and then submit the request to the API (either via server-side or client-side [AJAX] code).